# Trouble building P4Python with P4API

Tags: perforce, p4python

I'm trying to build P4Python, as described [here](http://public.perforce.com/guest/robert_cowham/perforce/API/python/old_p4python.html#build) and a more recent version found [here](http://slackbuilds.org/repository/13.37/python/p4python/).  I have the P4 API located at C:\p4api.  I have set the p4_api variable correctly in setup.cfg.  While in C:\P4Python-2010.1, which is where P4Python is extracted, I run the command `C:\P4Python-2010.1>python setup.py install > log.txt` to install it.

However, I get a ton of unresolved externals as shown in log.txt (these are only a few):

```
P4Result.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: static char * StrBuf::nullStrBuf" (?nullStrBuf@StrBuf@@0PADA) referenced in function __ehhandler$?Fmt@P4Result@@AAEXPBDPAU_object@@AAVStrBuf@@@Z
PythonMergeData.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static char * StrBuf::nullStrBuf" (?nullStrBuf@StrBuf@@0PADA)
P4MapMaker.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static char * StrBuf::nullStrBuf" (?nullStrBuf@StrBuf@@0PADA)
P4API.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static char * StrBuf::nullStrBuf" (?nullStrBuf@StrBuf@@0PADA)
```

I have no idea where it's looking to find these things or where they should be.  I added the P4API directory to PATH, and I still get the errors.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? x86? x64?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the Python release could you also provide the P4API (exact Version string) you are using?

By thy way, you can make your life easier by going to the Perforce public to find pre-built binary releases here:

http://public.perforce.com:8080/guest/sven_erik_knop/P4Pythonlib/bin/?ac=83

Kind regards

Sven Erik

PS:

You can also contact support@perforce.com for any questions relating to Perforce and the P4API.

Comment: I know it's been years since this post, but that link takes you to Perforce's SWARM page. Is there a newer link for that?

Answer (score 0):

Yep: https://swarm.workshop.perforce.com/projects/p4pythonlib/files/p4pythonlib/bin

By the way, p4python is now in the PyPi archives, so you could simply use (for Python 2.7, 3.3 and 3.4, both 32 and 64 bit)

pip install p4python

Answer (score 0):

this is new repo location on github,
https://github.com/perforce/p4python
according to
https://github.com/perforce/p4python/blob/master/RELNOTES.txt
since 2015 it can be installed via pip

**Installation via pip**

P4Python can be installed via pip from 2015.1 onwards. Simply run the command

`pip install p4python`